# incorrect tf results

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I tried to make a node that gives me the distance between the fixed point and the baselink over the time. But I get wrong distances. hould be in the range of 0 to some like 10 meters. But I got totaly uncenece datas.. like start from 5 and than go till 15 . So no cence results

This is my node

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_listener");

  ros::NodeHandle node;
  tf::TransformListener listener;

  ros::Rate rate(10.0);

  while (node.ok())

    {
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try{
      listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/door1",  
                               ros::Time(0), transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }


    double x = transform.getOrigin().x();
        double y = transform.getOrigin().y();
    double dist1 = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    ROS_INFO("%f", dist1);

    rate.sleep();


  }
  return 0;
};
```

And this the label in the launch file

Any help???

This my frames.pdf[image: image description]

Yes Sure

The output of

rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /door1 is

```
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.651, 10.067, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.532, 0.847]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -1.122]
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.651, 10.067, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.532, 0.847]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -1.122]
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.651, 10.067, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.532, 0.847]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -1.122]
^CAt time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.651, 10.067, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.532, 0.847]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -1.122]

and the distance is 

[ INFO] [1345720655.721469719, 1301628270.653578061]:  Dist to Door1 =11.086891
[ INFO] [1345720655.868379126, 1301628270.793675137]:  Dist to Door1 =11.087869
[ INFO] [1345720656.020382546, 1301628270.803828608]:  Dist to Door1 =11.090092
[ INFO] [1345720656.039301088, 1301628270.950554490]:  Dist to Door1 =11.090092
```

And the output of rosrun tf tf_echo /world /door1

```
At time 1301628270.978
- Translation: [4.500, 4.500, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 1301628270.978
- Translation: [4.500, 4.500, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
At time 1301628270.978
- Translation: [4.500, 4.500, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
^CAt time 1301628270.978
- Translation: [4.500, 4.500, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]

[ INFO] [1345721049.231849091, 1301628270.478065900]:  Dist to Door1 =6.513392
[ INFO] [1345721049.371391812, 1301628270.634387495]:  Dist to Door1 =6.513717
[ INFO] [1345721049.535096985, 1301628270.778485784]:  Dist to Door1 =6.513787
[ INFO] [1345721049.536815193, 1301628270.778485784]:  Dist to Door1 =6.513787
[ INFO] [1345721049.673510162, 1301628270.947420969]:  Dist to Door1 =6.513787
```

And from the rosrun tf tf_echo /world /base_link

```
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.850, 2.665, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.811, 0.586]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 1.890]
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.850, 2.665, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.811, 0.586]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 1.890]
At time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.850, 2.665, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.811, 0.586]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 1.890]
^CAt time 1301628270.947
- Translation: [4.850, 2.665, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.811, 0.586]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 1.890]

[ INFO] [1345721361.623291271, 1301628270.605040589]:  Dist to Door1 =1.868834
[ INFO] [1345721361.767260212, 1301628270.773273617]:  Dist to Door1 =1.869268
[ INFO] [1345721361.918387565, 1301628270.910657656]:  Dist to Door1 =1.868726
[ INFO] [1345721361.918494447, 1301628270.910657656]:  Dist to Door1 =1.868726
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42039/incorrect-tf-results/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
What is the comment or answer of the question? I can not see it

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-08-22**:
Can you post the output of these commands?

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /door1
rosrun tf tf_echo /world /door1
rosrun tf tf_echo /world /base_link
```

... along with the distances you get (i.e., the output of your program)?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-23**:
i just post it

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-23**:
Please always set the tags correctly to maximize the chance that the right people who can answer your question get notified.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-23**:
Ok, How to set this tag???

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-08-23**:
You can retag your question by clicking the "retag" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I tried to make a node that gives me the distance between the fixed point and the baselink over the time.
> [...]
>
> ```
>   listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/door1",  
>                           ros::Time(0), transform);
> ```

What are you trying to do? Find the distance between `/world` and `/base_link` or between `base_link` and `door1`? Your explanation and your code don't match.

Also, I am a little confused what your "Dist to Door1" outputs mean. In the first two cases, it seems as if they give the distance between the frames you mention in the `rosrun tf tf_echo` output, but the third one seems to be wrong.

From the `tf_echo` outputs it seems that everything is correct: `/door1` is about 6.5 meters away from `/world`, `/base_link` is about 5.5 meters away from `/world`, and because they are rotated by about 180° and `/world` is almost in the middle between the two frames, the total distance from `/base_link` to `/door1` is about 11 m.

You have to look at the RPY angles (in radian). Simply put, the rotation is applied before the translation.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0